# Can I create a swagger or other API documentation from Angular Services?

Tags: angular, api, http, swagger, documentation

I created an Angular app before creating a backend. Is there a service/npm package/library/etc I can use that scans the whole app services and its http requests and generate a swagger so the backend dev uses that?

I know there are some tools to do it the other way around (generate Angular Services out of a swagger) but I already have the code, I want to create the documentation for the endpoints I am using/expecting

Comment: it seems there is no such tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compodoc` should be able to to Generate json by following JSDoc annotations added to Angular service methods. https://compodoc.github.io/compodoc-demo-todomvc-angular/index.html which then can be fed to swagger.

`npm install -g @compodoc/compodoc`

Then configure compdoc

```
{
  "title": "My Angular App API Documentation",
  "sourceDir": "src/app",
  "exportFormats": ["swagger"]
}
```

Annotate services

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * A service for interacting with the My API.
 */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyApiService {
  /**
   * Retrieves the list of users.
   * @returns An observable that emits the list of users.
   */
  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('/api/users');
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

To generate swagger.json

```
compodoc -p tsconfig.app.json
```

Output file can be then given to BE guys?